# Alarm manager above oreo

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo

I have created a simple alarm clock.

It's working in above and below oreo+ but the issue is when I close the app in above oreo+ the alarm is not working.

```java
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent nIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyAlarm.class);
nIntent.setFlags(FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1234, nIntent, 0);
//creating a pending intent using the intent
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (int)alarmPeriodicTime, nIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
} else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
}
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set "+new Date(alarmPeriodicTime), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Did you got the solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.